# Having an issue with steps definition

Tags: python, function, exception, testcomplete

Writing my test case with test complete Python in Gerkin language. Everything was working and now Test cases does not seeing the step definition. When I am trying to regenerate the steps I am getting incorrect syntax in the step definition exception. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHGNo.png). There is  no {screen} in this test case:
Background: Run APAR.NET App and login
Given I run the application and see the login screen displayed
When I enter Username
And I enter password
Then I click the login button go to main window
When I open Accounts Payable submenu item
Then Accounts Payable screen is displayed
When I put a Begin Date, End Date and Check Date into the fields

```
@smoke @regression
```

Scenario: Verify Vouchers on Account Payable screen - TC315013 - TC300664

When I click the Select Vouchers button

Then The vouchers data loads to the screen

Then I close Accounts Payable screen

And I close the PS.NET

How come it is not seeing any of step definition in all project.
What can I do with that?

When I am trying to regenerate the steps I am getting incorrect syntax in the step definition exception.

Comment: Just an idea: 1. save the implementations of all your steps somewhere outside of your project. 2. In TestComplete: *Delete* the script files with the implementations of all your steps. 3. Let TestComplete regenerate the implementation of your steps. 4. Restore the implementation of your steps by coping the implementation from the backup. Important: Copy just the code inside the functions, not the funtion signatures. After that, all should be right with the world again. The only downside is that we don't know the reason for the original errors. I hope this helps. Regards